# Where can I find the Atom installation directory?

Tags: 15.10, paths, atom

I am running Ubuntu 15.10. After downloading the Atom editor, I can not find where exactly on my system it is installed. I tried running `which atom` `/usr/bin/atom`

However, after navigating to the `/bin` directory, I can only find a text file named Atom with some code in it, and not the actual application.

I need the application file because I want to select it in my web browser so that I can open files directly into Atom, without saving them into my computer. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Just type `atom` in the terminal and it will launch - it has a launch script, that's why you see text in the file

Comment: I figured how to launch it. But I need to launch it from my web browser, so I need the application file itself

Comment: Nevermind, I was not aware this could launch the application. My bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file `atom` in `/usr/bin` *is* the shell script which launches the `atom` binary file.

Comment: I was not aware this could launch the application. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to get the application itself, and not the script?

Comment: @abruzzi26 I'd take under consideration that there's probably a good reason for the existence of the script and use it for the purpose you asked about. If you think you know better, you could simply [look at the source](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/atom.sh#L94-L98) of the script and find out what it does, now that you know where to find it.

Comment: The atom binary file is in `/usr/share/atom`, if that helps. So running `/usr/share/atom/atom` should launch Atom, although I stand by idleberg's recommendation to use the `/usr/bin/atom` shell script to launch Atom.

Comment: Why can't I reach inside `cd ~/usr/bin` with `~`

Comment: @GiorgiGvimradze Because `~` is your home path and `usr` is located at the root, not your home path.

Comment: @JoshPinto thanks your solution worked. I used it to change default editor in Firezilla.